# Strange Kids Playing in a Nice Place

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, anagram

I am just back from a wonderful place and can't help sharing my experiences!

The place is really fun and amazing. There are movie theatres, libraries, music stores and what not! But I don't usually pay much attention to them, so I went straightaway to the playground, where I found many children at play. Curious, I called some of the kids and asked their names, but they gave quite strange answers:

> Occasionally you don't survive
>
> The same stage once more
>
> Stupid methods to end your life
>
> Fleeing in a holy place
>
> Specks in your head
>
> Royal encounter
>
> The chamber

"Hey, are you all crazy? I need to talk to your parents, who are your fathers?" I exclaimed. They appeared confused; nevertheless, they answered, in that order:

> Limp Personality Help
>
> Mir Taiga
>
> Terminators
>
> Amusing Idiots
>
> Stint Criminal
>
> Wee Six-seller
>
> Forgeries Of Map

Where did I go? More importantly, who are  those kids and their parents?

Hints:

> Most people have been there, especially those who use human-like robots.
>  Don't look for anagrams where they don't seem to be.

Comment: Can we assume that the children answered both times in the same order?

Comment: @Radoslav Yes you can.

Comment: Do the anagrams give specific names??

Comment: @Sid Some of them do. But beware, not everything in blockquotes is an anagram...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> the google play store. The kids are games and the fathers are the developers, hidden behind anagrams.

Occasionally you don't survive | Limp Personality Help

> Sometimes You Die |Philipp Stollenmayer

The same stage once more | Mir Taiga

> That level again | IamTagir

Stupid methods to end your life | Terminators

> Dumb ways to die | Metro Trains

Fleeing in a holy place |Amusing Idiots

> Temple Run | Imangi Studios (solved by **Arth**)

Specks in your head | Stint Criminal

> Brain Dots | Translimit, Inc

Royal encounter | Wee Six-seller

> Clash of Kings | Elex Wireless (solved by **Arth**)

The chamber | Forgeries Of Map

> The room | Fireproof games

Comment: Nice! I've added the two remaining ones (copied them from Arth's answer) for the sake of completeness. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Following up on @Namisca's answer:

Fleeing in a holy place

> Temple Run | Imangi Studios

Royal encounter

> Clash of Kings | Elex Wireless

Comment: That finishes it.:) BTW, Google tells me it's Imangi Studios; I took the liberty to go in and edit it. :)

Comment: @Ankoganit Ah, you are of course correct.. I misread it! Thanks :)